# don't know what to do with file "/root/livedb/filename.metadata.json.gz", skipping

Tags: mongodb, collections, mongodb-atlas, atlas

I have taken mongodb dump from atlas mongo db and restore to AWS document DB.

When i am restore to document db getting below error

**don't know what to do with file "/root/livedb/filename.metadata.json.gz", skipping...**

How can i resolve this issue.

Comment: I have used below command to take dump from atlas

mongodump --uri "mongodb+srv://clustername.mongodb.net/?authSource=%24external&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&retryWrites=true&w=majority&sslClientCertificateKeyFile=/home/ubuntu/filename.pem" --out /root/

Comment: mongorestore --ssl --host="hostname:27017" --username=<username>--password=<password> --authenticationDatabase=admin --sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem /path

Comment: The above command i have used for restore that's why i am getting above the error, How to resolve this issue.

Comment: Why `/root/` on one and `/path` on the other?

Comment: I have changed other directory also but getting same error.

Comment: I have refer some blogs it says add -d --db and --nsInclude i have tried that too, but samething happend.

Comment: If that mongodump command line you showed (without a --gzIp option) actually creates a .gz file, something is not right.  Perhaps you need to make sure the directory is empty before dumping.

Comment: Yes Joe, Directory is empty before taking dump

Comment: mongodump doesn't compress by default, what is compressing the file?

Comment: This is the sample file name    ALbEKzrkWknkcaWCTJXyAPZF.bson.gz", skipping...

Comment: Again with the `.gz`, are you sure that is the correct command line in the first comment?

Comment: mongorestore --gzip --host="hostname:27017" -u <username>-p <password>authenticationDatabase=admin --sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem  /home/ubuntu/atlaslivedb/

Comment: I have tried with that command with another directory.

Comment: Atlas MongoDB Version 6.0   AWS Document DB Version is 5.0